# Programmatically list intent-filters

Tags: android, android-activity, intentfilter

In an android Activity is there a way to programmatically list the  it has registered for?

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I'm trying to determine if the current Activity is a LAUNCHER.

Comment: The fact that you want to do this indicates something badly designed in your app, what are you needing to do this for?

Comment: not necessarily, don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski do you need to know why developers are doing that? you're too judgmental, mate, and who do you think you are? there are some cases that best practices and standards aren't going to fulfill very specific use cases. I've seen many software companies promoting best practices, design patterns, etc. yet in many app they produced I discovered a lot of bad designs and high usage of deprecated APIs. I don't consider them bad, as long as it works for them and their users, then it's good.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski this is very useful if you want to write unit tests which test the correctness of your AndroidManifest.xml file. Particularly if you have a complex multi flavor project with merged manifests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the package manager will tell you what you're looking for.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

```
public abstract ActivityInfo getActivityInfo (ComponentName component, int flags)
```

where flags may contain

```
GET_INTENT_FILTERS
```

Comment: Is it working for you?
It seems that this flag is not really supported https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3217