# How programmatically get URI for Deep Linking from Android manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, deep-linking, android-package-managers

I need to send URI for Deep Link from Android manifest to the server  - is it possible to get URL scheme programmatically?

Or may be  change Android manifest programmatically and add new scheme after app start.

Thanks!

Comment: "I need to send scheme from Android manifest" -- what do you mean by "scheme"? "is it possible to get it programmatically?" -- what is "it" in the phrase "get it"? "Or may be change Android manifest programmatically" -- that is not possible. The closest you can come is to enable and disable components (e.g., activities, services) via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`.

Comment: By "scheme" I mean scheme for Deep Links like this  <data android:scheme="http"    android:host="www.example.com" android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />  .

Comment: setComponentEnabledSetting() not works for me, thanks!  By "get it" I mean get android:scheme,  sorry for my English. May be you know, is it possible to get  all data from Manifest?

Comment: I do not know of a good way to get at data in `<intent-filter>` elements, sorry.

Comment: Basically it is not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814989/programmatically-list-intent-filters/9815172#9815172 Unfortunately, this does not work as documented. :-( See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3217

Comment: yep, this is sad:( .... I will try get all content from manifest..

Comment: Get AndroidManifest file: [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097813/how-to-parse-the-androidmanifest-xml-file-inside-an-apk-package)
then convert to xml and parse xml.